# Getting more than one metric from Cloudwatch using Boto3

Tags: python-3.x, boto3, amazon-cloudwatch

Suppose I have a lambda called 'my_lambda' for which I want to get 2 metrics using the boto3 API. Here is how I would get a single metric statistic at 10 minute intervals:

```
import boto3
import time
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date, timezone

cloudwatch = boto3.client('cloudwatch', region_name=region_name)

#Use get_metric_statistics
stat_response = cloudwatch.get_metric_statistics(        
    Namespace="AWS/Lambda",
    MetricName="Duration",
    Dimensions=[
        {
            "Name": "FunctionName",
            "Value": "my_lambda"
        }
    ],
    StartTime=datetime(2023, 3, 27, 12, 12, 13),
    EndTime=datetime.now(),
    Period=600,
    Statistics=["Average"],
)

print(stat_response)
```

Now I want to add the metric `"Errors"`. Is there a way to pull both metrics at the same time for a single lambda?

Comment: I Don't think that's possible with this APi, as the [API docs mention](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/API_GetMetricStatistics.html) that it allows you to get a single metric with each API call. is there a problem with two calls?

Comment: I suppose not, but it just complicates my overall code. And increases the runtime.